# CSS grid is stacking up on desktop

Tags: php, css, grid, css-grid

I have created a page to display grid but the CSS grid is showing stacked up in desktop view. I can't figure out why it is happening. Here's the code:

CSS

I added the `<div class="row">` as well to indicate that these are part of the same row. I have tried to divide it into 4 columns and then use span to indicate the width. But none of them is

```css
 #grid-list-page {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
     grid-gap: 1px;
    }
    .listUL {
      padding: 2px;
      margin: 1px;
      height: 200px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .listUL li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 1em;
      padding: 0;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
      #grid-list-page {
       grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      }
    }
```

```html
 <div id="grid-list-page">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="grid-item">
       <h4>List for USA</h4>
       <ul id="usalistUL" class="listUL">
        <?php
         $args = array( 
         'post_type'  => 'post', 
         'numberposts'  => -1,
         'meta_query' => array(
          array(
           'key' => 'list_country',
           'value' => 'usa',
          ),
         ),   
         );
         $usaposts = get_posts($args);
         foreach($usaposts as $usapost) { 
          $post_id = $usapost->ID; ?>
          <li>
           <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($post_id); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a>
          </li>
        <?php } ?>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
       <h4>List for Canada</h4>
       <ul id="canlistUL" class="listUL">
        <?php
         $args = array( 
         'post_type'  => 'post', 
         'numberposts'  => -1,
         'meta_query' => array(
          array(
           'key' => 'list_country',
           'value' => 'canada',
          ),
         ),   
         );
         $canposts = get_posts($args);
         foreach($canposts as $canpost) { 
          $post_id = $canpost->ID; ?>
          <li>
           <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($post_id); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a>
          </li>
        <?php } ?>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

working for some reason. I have a grid on another page which is working correctly using the same structure but this one isn't working. Any guidance would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the `<div class="row> </div>` and it seems to work. Here is the html code:

```
<div id="grid-list-page">
    <div class="grid-item">
        <h4>List for USA</h4>
        <ul id="usalistUL" class="listUL">
            <?php
                $args = array( 
                'post_type'     => 'post', 
                'numberposts'   => -1,
                'meta_query'    => array(
                    array(
                        'key'   => 'list_country',
                        'value' => 'usa',
                    ),
                ),          
                );
                $usaposts = get_posts($args);
                foreach($usaposts as $usapost) { 
                    $post_id = $usapost->ID; ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($post_id); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a>
                    </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <h4>List for Canada</h4>
        <ul id="canlistUL" class="listUL">
            <?php
                $args = array( 
                'post_type'     => 'post', 
                'numberposts'   => -1,
                'meta_query'    => array(
                    array(
                        'key'   => 'list_country',
                        'value' => 'canada',
                    ),
                ),          
                );
                $canposts = get_posts($args);
                foreach($canposts as $canpost) { 
                    $post_id = $canpost->ID; ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($post_id); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a>
                    </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is another example of the css grid property: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-column.asp

Comment: I had added the <div class="row"> following the suggestion on stackoverflow. Its not working at my end for some reason.

Comment: That is weird...Here is a Codepen link where it is working fine https://codepen.io/mrcj101111/pen/zypNZN

Comment: Yes I know it works on post template as well but for some reason it doesn't work on the page template.